# How to filter views output base on custom field

Tags: views

I've created a view listing a content type named *foo*, it has a custom field 'start_date' which can be left blank.

When a node's *start_date* field is left blank, it should always show in the listing. When it's populated, and the date is less than the current date - then the node should also be listed.

I've tried to use `hook_views_query_alter` to do this, but it didn't do what I wanted as it's for changing the query itself.

Which hook should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Views UI to accomplish this.

Add two date filters: one of them should filter date fields for "is empty" and the other should filter date fields for "is less than" and choose "Enter relative date" and type "now".

Then create an "OR" group and drag the two date filters to it. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @argiepiano.
Thans for your kindly comment. It's a great answer! But i have a another question complementary.Is it possible only worked for a special user role.
Example if current user's role is 'trainee', then the filter is efficient and if role is admin the filter was bypassed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that with Views UI. You could try creating a custom filter programmatically that returns true for admin and false for everyone else, and include that in two OR groups. A tutorial on creating a custom filter: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-filters-views. Otherwise, Views PHP is a module that is despised by many Drupal programmers, but it *may* work for something like (keeping in mind that it poses many serious security risks.)

Comment: One more thing, since you are new to Drupal Answers - if you find answers useful you can vote them up or mark them as correct. That encourages people to provide other answers.

Comment: The tutorial above may not be that helpful in your case.

Comment: Take a look at this post. This may have what you need: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/d7-filter-a-view-based-on-current-users-roles (look at the answer marked as correct)